# Finding the additive inverse of an element of a ring of sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, set-theory

In Real Analysis (Haaser, Sullivan) Chapter 1, question 11 goes as follows:

> If symmetric difference is taken as addition and intersection is taken as multiplication, show that a ring of sets is a commutative ring in the algebraic sense. What is the additive inverse of an element of this ring?

So far with this question I have:

> 1. Let R be a ring of sets in the powerset P(X).
> 2. A Δ B ∈ R = {x ∈ A or x ∈ B: ~(x ∈ A and x ∈ B)} (A Δ B ∈ R was proven in a previous problem)
>
>    - = {x ∈ A or x ∈ B: x ∉ A or x ∉ B}
>    - = {x ∈ A or x ∈ B: x ∈ A if and only if x ∉ B)
>    - = {x ∈ B or x ∈ A: x ∈ B if and only if x ∉ A) = B Δ A.
> 3. A Δ B = B Δ A for all A ∈ R.
> 4. A ∩ B = {x ∈ X: x ∈ A and x ∈ B for some A,B ∈ R}
>
>    - = {x ∈ X: x ∈ B and x ∈ A for some A,B ∈ R} = B ∩ A.
> 5. A ∩ B = B ∩ A for all A,B ∈ R.
> 6. Therefore, if symmetric difference is taken as addition and intersection is taken as multiplication, then R is a commutative ring.

So my issue is with the second half of the question, that is, finding the additive inverse of an element of R. An additive inverse must satisfy the condition a + (-a) = 0, and this is where I run into a problem with regards to taking symmetric difference as addition. If A,B are sets in R,and R is a ring of sets in the powerset P(X), A Δ (~A) does not yield the empty set but instead yields the superset X. A Δ A on the other hand, yields the empty set, but does not satisfy the condition a + (-a) = 0. Yet, if we take intersection as addition instead of symmetric difference we can satisfy the condition a + (-a) = 0 since A ∩ (~A) yields the empty set, but this go against the prompt to treat symmetric difference as addition and intersection as multiplication.

Comment: Be careful with "0" and "-". These symbols mean the additive identity and the additive inverse (respectively), not necessarily the empty set and the set complement operation.

Comment: @Karl What would be the additive identity and additive inverse in this instance?

Comment: @Karl It seems that ∅ would be the additive identity if we're taking symmetric difference as addition, since for A ∈ R, A Δ ∅ = A.

Comment: Yep, $\emptyset$ does turn out to be the additive inverse.

Answer (score 1):

If you were trying to figure out the additive identity for the first time, your train of thought might go like this.

"Well, in an abelian group the additive identity is the only thing that satisfies $x+x=x$. What does that mean using sets and symmetric difference?"

In your case, it looks like $X\Delta X=X$. For an element $x$ to be in the left hand side, it has to satisfy $x\in (X\setminus X)\cup(X\setminus X))=\emptyset\cup \emptyset=\emptyset$.  That's a contradiction of course, unless $X$ is already empty.

So now we know $\emptyset$ is the identity for $\Delta$.  You already noticed that $A\Delta A=\emptyset$ for any $A$, and in order for  $\Delta$ to define an abelian group operation on your ring, you'd need $A$ to be the additive inverse of $A$, because additive inverses are unique.

But this all hinges on knowing $\Delta$ really makes it into an abelian group. This line of thinking gave us the right suspect for the additive inverse, but the task to be completed has not been accomplished.

What's left for you to do is to verify those axioms, and hopefully the path is clear now because you already recognize what the identity and inverses have to be to accomplish that.

Comment: So it is allowed for an element as its own additive inverse? How does that sit with the book defining it by a + (-a) = 0?

Comment: @Matt It just means $a=-a$, which has nothing contradictory about it. For arithmetic mod $2$, you always have that. And indeed, the ring of sets with this operation is closely related to that.